# equivalent to ngAfterViewInit but general for all views

Tags: javascript, angular

When views DOM is heavy, sometimes it gets some time to render it, especially on older mobile devices. I would like to put a spinner whenever the view is not rendered yet.

I can achieve that using ngAfterViewInit hook but doing it for every view provides a lot of duplicated code.

I was wondering if there is a global hook that is fired whenever rendering of current view is done.

Comment: No, there is no such hook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jota mentioned in a comment, what you're asking for doesn't exist in angular. Something you could do, which may or may not be appropriate to your situation, is add a single spinner component to the root of your app (say, in `app.component.ts`) and create a service which can turn it on or off. This way, in each of your child components you could turn the spinner on in `ngOnInit` and turn it off in `ngAfterViewInit`.

Another option, if you're using the Angular Router, is to have this spinner component listen for router events: turning on at `NavigationStart` and turning off at `NavigationEnd`.